# Apache Airflow: How to write BigQuery Query results to GCS Bucket directly (without intermediate table) in python DAG?

Tags: python, google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage, airflow, directed-acyclic-graphs

DAG code in Python which uses intermediate table write concept. But instead need to write this query results directly to GCS Bucket as csv file. Also, `csv file extension` should hold the `max date` used in query.

```
# Query results written to intermediate table
BQ_Output =  BigQueryOperator(
    task_id='BQ_Output',
    write_disposition='WRITE_TRUNCATE',
    use_legacy_sql=False,
    allow_large_results=True, 
    sql="""
    CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE `schema.result_table` as (
    SELECT * except (store_name, state, week_start_date, season) FROM `schema.result_table` where week_start_date = (SELECT MAX(week_start_date) FROM `schema.result_table`))
    """, 
    params=var_config,
    dag=dag)
  
  
# Results Table to GCS Bucket  
Bq_GCS = BigQueryToCloudStorageOperator(
    task_id = 'Bq_GCS',
    source_project_dataset_table = "schema.result_table",
    destination_cloud_storage_uris = "gs://bucket_path/output_<max_date>_file.csv",
    export_format = 'CSV',
    field_delimiter = ',',
    dag = dag
)
```

Kindly help me through this. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider using **EXPORT DATA**

```sql
DECLARE max_date DATE DEFAULT (SELECT MAX(week_start_date) FROM `schema.result_table`)

EXPORT DATA OPTIONS (
  uri = 'gs://bucket_path/output_' || FORMAT_DATE('%Y%m%d', max_date) || '/_file_*.csv',
  format = 'CSV',
  overwrite = true,
  header = false,
  field_delimiter = ','
) AS
SELECT * except (store_name, state, week_start_date, season) FROM `schema.result_table` where week_start_date = max_date;
```

Below is a sample task of Airflow DAG for BigQuery Script.

```py
BQ_Output = BigQueryInsertJobOperator(
    task_id='BQ_Output',
    configuration = {
        "query": {
            "query": """
              <put above script here>
            """,
            "useLegacySql": False
        }
    },
    location = 'asia-northeast3'
)
```

- https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/other-statements#export_data_statement

Comment: So which part of DAG I need to replace with the above code ?

Comment: If you dont' need a permanent **schema.result_table**,  you can replace **BQ_Output** task with **EXPORT DATA** script.  then, **Bq_GCS** task is not necessary anymore.